# Can an adverb be placed between a verb and its direct object?

Tags: verbs, adverbs, syntactic-analysis, objects

The direct object usually follows the verb, not the adverb. For example, we say *I love you deeply* instead of *I love deeply you.* However, there are instances where the direct object is so long that the adverb ends up far away from its verb. Is it correct to place the adverb *between* the verb and the direct object? See this example, where the adverb is placed immediately after the verb, and not after the direct object:

> In order to convey *accurately* all the shades of meaning that she had found while doing her research, she asked a few experts.

Does the length of the direct object affect the placement of the adverb? Thanks!

Comment: An easy solution would be to put the adverb before the verb: "I deeply love you."

Comment: "Asked" is your main verb here. It's awkward to place an adverb between the verb and the direct object. It works with an infinitive or other parts of speech. "She defended vigorously her right to choose" vs. "She vigorously defended Mary."

Comment: In speaking that sentence there probably would be emphasis on _accurately_ not present in the other version.  I.e. "In order to accurately convey all the shades..." vs "In order to convey--accurately--all the shades..."

Comment: It's quite routine to move heavy Noun Phrases like the one in the example sentence to the end of the sentence; [English syntactic rules](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/haj/Preliminarybufattenedlistoftransformations.pdf) like Extraposition (_It's hard to believe he actually said that_), _There_-Insertion (_There needs to be a whole lot more work going on here_), and Heavy-NP Shift (_He painted sky blue the little birdhouse_) are very common in English. This is a case of Extraposition from NP, which applies to NP complements and relative clauses (_A man walked in that I had never met before_).

Comment: Thanks, everyone. John is right. If you look for "Relative Clause Extraposition" you will find interesting information. At http://www1.icsi.berkeley.edu/~kay/bcg/extrap.html it gives the example "There's someone out there in the street who's asking about you," and explains: "In a number of contexts it is possible to find a relative clause, separated from its head noun, at the end of a sentence."